# Rails devise sign_out is giving No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Seems like this is a very common question, and I have followed many of the fixes from google, yet my sign-out problem persists.

Here's what I have: Rails 4.1.1, Devise 3.2.4. Oh, btw, instead of User, I am calling my model AppUser

On view

```
As AppUser: <br>
<% if app_user_signed_in? %>
    Signed in as: <%= current_app_user.email %> <br>
    <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_app_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>  
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_app_user_registration_path %> <br>
    <%= link_to "Sign In", new_app_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :app_users
  root 'home#index'
end
```

these are the partial routes from rake routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
    new_app_user_session GET    /app_users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        app_user_session POST   /app_users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_app_user_session DELETE /app_users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

on application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

on application.html.erb, i included this as well

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

and yet, i am still getting the get route error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/app_users/sign_out"
```

Why????

Ok. 
So, changing :delete to :get on /config/initializer/devise.rb fixes the problem, with method: :delete removed of course.

```
# The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

But I still don't get it? Why? If I were to keep :delete on devise.rb, what was I missing?

========================

[SOLVED]
I probably should edit the status update here:

I have finally figured out why. Even though i have set up my javascript, etc, correctly, but it didn't load because I stupidly inherit my controller class from "ActionController::Base" instead of "ApplicationController".

As I was working through my project, I noticed link_tos on other pages weren't able to send :delete method either.

Once I fixed the inheritance, they all work.

Gah.

Comment: that's weird, the only way i can recreate that error is to put the direction directly... can you post your routes file?

Comment: What does your config/routes.rb say

Comment: I added my routes.rb to my original post. Though the line concerning devise I believe is only 'devise_for :app_users', and that gave me a bunch of routes through rake routes, which partially I have included on the original post as well

Comment: this thing is driving me crazy. it must be something simple that I am missing. but i dont know what it is.

Comment: this has been asked *so many times*....

Comment: I agree. And I have spent a few hours looking through them. I thought I have followed all the instructions, yet, still... it's been bothering me since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out why. 
Even though i have set up my javascript, etc, correctly, but it didn't load because I stupidly inherit my controller class from "ActionController::Base" instead of "ApplicationController".

As I was working through my project, I noticed link_tos on other pages weren't able to send :delete method either.

Once I fixed the inheritance, they all work.

Gah.

Answer (score 0):

routes.rb

```
devise_scope :app_user do
  get "/app_users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery?**

> If I were to keep :delete on devise.rb, what was I missing?

From the looks of it, the issue is likely to do with your system not rendering / processing `:delete` HTTP verbs correctly. The issue will be a Javascript one, as this http verb is created by the rails UJS on a standard `get` link

I would suggest you either have some problems with other javascript files on your system (check the browser console), or you are not loading the `jquery_ujs` file properly

The best way to test this will be to firstly look at the `browser console`, then see if you can bind an action to event inside your JS:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "#test_link", function(){
    alert("test");
});
```